# mysql INSERT INTO syntax error - Newish User:)

Tags: php, mysql

I get the following error when trying to run the an INSERT statement:

> ERROR: INSERT INTO company (`company`, `adr_street`, `city`, `Prov`,
>   `postal`, `country`) VALUES (company1, 67 46 street sw, city1,
>   province1, w9w9w9, Canada) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '46 street sw, city1, province1, w9w9w9,
>   Country)' at line 1

This is the vardump:

> array(7) { ["company"]=> string(8) "company1" ["adr_street"]=>
>   string(15) "67 46 street sw" ["city"]=> string(5) "city1" ["prov"]=>
>   string(9) "province1" ["postal"]=> string(6) "w9w9w9" ["country"]=>
>   string(6) "Canada" ["Submit"]=> string(6) "submit" }

This is the query:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO company (`company`, `adr_street`, `city`, `Prov`, `postal`, `country`) VALUES ($company, $adr_street, $city, $prov, $postal, $country)";
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your text/string values with single quote like below.

```
INSERT INTO company (company, adr_street, city, Prov, postal, country) 
VALUES ('company1', '67 46 street sw', 'city1', 'province1', 'w9w9w9', 'Canada');
```